# How do I avoid my logo appearing more than once on my interactive navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create an interactive navigation bar which display a miniaturized logo when each entry of the menu gets flown by the mouse and when it's selected. As you can see with this code, I've managed to enable the logo to display when ".mouseenter()" and when the element gets clicked as well.

However, I would also need the logo to do not display again once the related `<li>` has been clicked.

Also, I'm seeking a way for the each selected html element to update its width without taking in account the ".mouseleave()" method.

Please give me your input, many thanks in advance !

```js
$(".nav-a").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("width","150px");
    $(this).prepend('<img class="logo-mini" src="img/logo-mini.png" style="float:left;margin-top:7%" />');
});

$(".nav-a").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".logo-mini").remove();
});

$(".nav-a").click(function(){
    $(".logo-mini").remove();
    $(".pictomark").remove();
    $(this).css("width","150px");
    $(this).prepend('<img class="pictomark" src="img/logo-mini.png" style="float:left;margin-top:7%" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-a">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a><!-- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-a">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-a">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-a">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-a">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Just remove the click all together then, also... why would you want to do this in JavaScript when you can use css?... i.e `.navbar-nav li a:before {width:150px; background: url("logo.png"); display:none;} .navbar-nav li a::hover::before {display: block;}`